# Changing sprintf to an array of characters C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a 2d array of words.

```
void main() {
    const int rowsCount = 2;
    const int colsCount = 5;

    char*** szData = new char** [rowsCount];

    //Allocate memory for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        szData[i] = new char* [colsCount]; //how many words in every row
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
        {
            szData[i][j] = new char[15]; //maximum symbols in a word
        }
    }

    //Assign some data
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        char s[] = "Williams";
        szData[i][0] = s;

        sprintf(szData[i][0], "Williams%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][1], "J.%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][2], "#3%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][3], "100%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][4], "01.13%d", 0);
    }
...
}
```

While assigning data, I tried to change this

```
sprintf(szData[i][0], "Williams%d");
```

to this

```
char s[] = "Williams";
szData[i][0] = s;
```

Why do I keep getting the message that my project "has trigerred a breakpoint"?

Is there any alternative to `sprintf` using array of characters? Cannot use `string` (one of the condition of this task)

Also, not so necessary, but if I delete 0 at the end here

```
sprintf(szData[i][0], "Williams%d", 0);
sprintf(szData[i][1], "J.%d", 0);
sprintf(szData[i][2], "#3%d", 0);
sprintf(szData[i][3], "100%d", 0);
sprintf(szData[i][4], "01.13%d", 0);
```

there will appear some numbers after every word. For example: `Williams3937516`. Why is that?

Full code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std;

void main() {
    const int rowsCount = 2;
    const int colsCount = 5;

    char*** szData = new char** [rowsCount];

    //Allocate memory for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        szData[i] = new char* [colsCount]; //how many words in every row
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
        {
            szData[i][j] = new char[15]; //maximum symbols in a word
        }
    }

    //Assign some data
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        char s[] = "Williams";
        szData[i][0] = s;

        sprintf(szData[i][0], "Williams%d");
        sprintf(szData[i][1], "J.%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][2], "#3%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][3], "100%d", 0);
        sprintf(szData[i][4], "01.13%d", 0);
    }

    //print all the elements
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
        {
            cout << szData[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

    //free memory here
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
        {
            delete[] szData[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        delete[] szData[i];
    }

    delete[] szData;
}
```

Comment: If your intent is to write C++ code, you want to use C++ containers, like `vector`s, to correctly manage all the memory allocations for you, accurately and correctly. The above looks like bug-prone C code instead of C++. Modern C++ rarely needs to use `new` or `delete`. There's some kind of a bug in the shown code regarding memory allocation, but rather than wasting time trying to figure out what it is, a much simpler solution is to make it logically impossible for this kind of a bug to happen. Scrap everything, and rewrite it from scratch using modern C++ container and iterator-based code.

Comment: I'm studying at university and cannot do it using `vector` yet, unfortunately (another condition of the task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace back the assignment of this pointer:

`char s[] = "Williams";`

You'll find you are attempting to free its memory here:

`delete[] szData[i][j];`

However, you can't do that -- the string `"Williams"` was never allocated with `new`, so it can't be freed with `delete`.  In fact, it's statically allocated, in your binary.  So the heap complains, and that's the cause of the breakpoint.

If you're going to `delete` everything in `szData`, you need to make sure it's all allocated on the heap with `new`.

Second problem - when you call:

`sprintf(szData[i][0], "Williams%d", 0);`

You're overwriting the bounds of the memory you supplied.  Remember, your buffer only has `"Williams"` number of bytes (plus one)!  You don't have space to tack an integer's string representation on the end of that.  Use `sprintf_s` and make sure your buffers have enough room!

Third problem - writing to statically allocated string data is enormously sketchy and may not work in all cases.

Bottom line: dynamic allocate a buffer of the right size for everything, and your code will work.

Here's a simple example to fix that section of code.  It demonstrates the concepts that fix your code, but it's not really appropriate for your codebase as-is, you'll need to work it in properly.

```cpp
const size_t MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 15; // Fix this magic number to be whatever max name length you want
char *s = new char[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];  // allocate on heap
strcpy_s(s, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, "Williams");  // use strcpy_s for safety
     
szData[i][0] = s;
sprintf_s(szData[i][0], MAX_NAME_LENGTH, "Williams%d", 0);  // use sprintf_s for safety
```

Comment: `strcpy_s` and `sprintf_s` are optional in Standard C++ (many compilers may not provide them)